# How to overload default c# get set?

Tags: c#, get, set

I want to overload default get set methods of c#. I could not achieve to write get(int index), and set(int index, int value) by not changing the original contenI want to overload default get set methods of c#. I could not achieve to write get(int index), and set(int index, int value) by not changing the original content. Below code just does not compile.

```
    private int xx[2];

    public int Xx 
    {
        get (int index)
        {
            return xx[index == 1];
        }

        set (int index)
        {
            xx[index == 1] = value;
        }
    }
```

. Below code just does not compile.

```
    private int xx[2];

    public int Xx 
    {
        get (int index)
        {
            return xx[index == 1];
        }

        set (int index)
        {
            xx[index == 1] = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you refer to is called [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/). In c#, to create indexers, you use the keyword `this`, followed by square brackets and then get (and an optional set):

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get { return arr[i]; }
    set { arr[i] = value; }
}
```

In your case it's not really obvious what your code should go, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
private int xx[2];

public int this[index] 
{
    get { return xx[index]; }
    set { xx[index] = value; }
}
```